# How to trigger an on-prem Jenkins job when opening a PR on github

Tags: github, jenkins

I have a public Github repo and an on-prem Jenkins server (this could not be changed)

I want a Jenkins job to start every time a PR is opened in the github repo.

Now, if my Jenkins had public access I will simply set up a webhook on github, but since github can not access my Jenkins what can I do to trigger the job?

Is there an option to set a webhook the other way around? meaning the Jenkins will check every few seconds/minutes if a PR was opened and if so it will trigger the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure the GitHub Pull Request Builder Plugin to poll for PR refspecs, although it works somewhat differently than using webhooks.

Alternatively, assuming you have connectivity from the on-premise environment to the outside, you can setup [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) / [webhook relay](https://webhookrelay.com/) / [smee](https://smee.io/) to have a publicly-accessible address that forwards GitHub webhooks. CloudBees have a [video on forwarding webhooks using ngrok](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yMNJeWeE0qI).

If a DMZ is possible then using tunnels such as [GitWebhookProxy](https://github.com/stakater/GitWebhookProxy), stunnel, or SSH are also good options.

Comment: Tnx. I will look into this and update you if it works :)